# What is the alternative for selected default in React?

Tags: html, reactjs

In the HTML, I got something like this for select.

What it's doing is the default value showing for the select dropdown is `Select year` but it cannot be selected.

```
<select>
    <option disabled hidden selected>
        Select Year
    </option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
</select>
```

But when I implement it in React.

It giving me this error

> Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on .

But when I use `default value` or `value`  the SELECT YEAR option is not there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to remove both `selected` and `disabled` attributes from first `<option>`:

```
<select>
  <option hidden>Select Year</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
</select>
```

Here's why:

`<select>` is shorthand for `<select defaultValue={undefined}>`, which makes the first `<option>` with a `value` of `undefined` get selected. In your case, that's the first `<option>`, since it doesn't have a set `value`, which is equivalent to having a `value` set to `undefined`.

Probably the most important bit is removing `disabled`. Remember this is [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), not [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML). JSX is used by React to create valid HTML. If you specify `disabled` attribute, React won't allow that `<option>` to be selected, regardless of method.
But you want that `<option>` selected by default, so it doesn't make sense to disable it.
You only want the user not to be able to select it, which is exactly what the `hidden` attribute does.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leaf-ol7yg4?file=/src/App.js).